# Javascript array cast into function logs as integer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function I am working on below. I cast an array called "IDs" into the function and am having no problem with it in the first "if" statement, but when you enter into the "else" statement, "IDs" is equating as an integer. You can see what I mean in the console.log comments right after the start of the else block. Can you see why "IDs" does not remain an array?

Where parameter is cast into function (see console.log "Is ID's array?"):

```
$j('select').change(function(e) { //on changing the attribute input
        if ($j(this).find('option:selected')[0].text=='Choose an Option...')//see if there is a value in the dropdown
        { 
            $j('#vendorsButton').removeClass().addClass('vendorsButtonOff'); //Gray out the button and disable
            $j("#vendorBox").hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $j('#vendorsButton').removeClass().addClass('vendorsButtonOn'); //Enable and make it gold


            var items = $j('#attribute136').children().length;//for the length of the select list (children of select)
            //console.log("There are " + items + " children in select parent.");
            var IDs = []; //collect all of the vendor ids in an array
            for (var i=2; i <= items; i++)
            {
                var text= $j('#attribute136 option:nth-child(' + i + ')').text();//get text of option
                var value= $j('#attribute136 option:nth-child(' + i + ')').val();//value of option for add to cart function
                console.log('Value to text is ' + value + ' : ' + text); 
                //console.log(text);
                IDs[i-2]= value;
            } 
            console.log('Is IDs an array? ' + IDs); //returns "5,3"
            //insert quantity box
            $j('#vendorBox').append("<div id='qtyUpdateBox'></div");
            $j('#qtyUpdateBox').append('<label for="qty">Qty:</label>'); 
            $j('#qtyUpdateBox').append('<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty" />');
            $j('#qtyUpdateBox').append('<a href="#" class="updatePriceButton" onclick="updatePrices('+IDs+')">Update</a>');
            //populate vendorBox
            $j('.vendorList').empty().removeClass('vendorList');
            $j('#vendorBox').append("<ul class='vendorList'></ul>");//make list 
            vendorInfo(IDs);
        }

    });
```

The first function that the parameter is cast into (this time it is called, it works just fine):

```
function vendorInfo(IDs){//AJAX CALL TO PHP SCRIPT TO OBTAIN VENDOR APPLICABLE VALUES

        $j.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax_calls/vendorInfo.php",
            //dataType:"json",
            data: { 'vendorID': IDs} //if passing array doesn't work try to construct json object
            }).done(function(data) {
                var data= JSON.parse(data);
                //console.log('success');
                //console.log('The data is for vendorinfo ');
                //console.log(data);
                for(var i=0; i < IDs.length; i++)
                {
                    //console.log('Data for ' + data[i].id);
                    $j('.vendorList').append("<li class='vendorListItem' id='" + data[i].id + "'><ul class='details" + data[i].id + "'><li class='vendorName'>" + data[i].id+': '+data[i].name+ "</li><li class='vendorDescription'>"+ data[i].description +"</li><li class='priceBlock'></li></ul></li>");//add text to list item
                    addToCartBlock(data[i].id);
                    //displayPrice(data[i].id);
                    //instead we will call updatePrice, which will display table value prices and save applicable price when addtocart function called
                }

                    $j('.vendorList').append('<div style="clear:both"></div>');
                    updatePrices(IDs);
            }); 
    }
```

The function that the parameter is cast into when the "update" button is hit (when the function is called an integer is being cast into it not an array as it should)
:

```
function updatePrices(IDs){
    var product_id= <?=$product_id ?>;
    //var price = <?=$_price ?>;
    var simpleArray = <?=json_encode($simpleArray)?>;
    var qty= $j("#qtyUpdateBox input").val();
    var colorSelected = $j("#attribute92 option:selected").val();
    //var IDs = IDs;

    if (qty==1){
        for(i=0; i<IDs.length; i++)
        {   
            var vendor = IDs[i]; 
            //CAITLIN you are going to need way to search for other attributes, GET list of attributes
            $j('.details'+vendor+ ' .priceBlock').append('<span>'+simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected]+'</span>');
        }
    }
    else{
        console.log('The Ids are ' + IDs.length); //equates to undefined
        console.log('The Ids are ' + IDs); //equates to "5"
        console.log('The Ids are ' + IDs[1]); //equates to undefined
        //ajax call to obtain tier prices for each vendor id
        $j.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax_calls/updatePrices.php",
                data: { 'vendorID': IDs, 'product_id': product_id}
                }).done(function(data,IDs,simpleArray) {
                    var data= JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log('Range start is ' + data.tier2_range_start);
                    for(i=0; i<IDs.length; i++)
                    {   
                        var vendor = IDs[i]; 
                        console.log('The vendor is ' + vendor[1]);
                        var basePrice = simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected];

                        if (qty < data.tier2_range_start){
                            simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected]= basePrice * qty;
                        }
                        else if (qty > data.tier2_range_start){
                            simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected]= (basePrice * qty) * tier2_discount;
                        }
                        else if (qty > data.tier3_range_start){
                            simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected]= (basePrice * qty) * tier3_discount;
                        }
                        else if (qty > data.tier4_range_start){
                            simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected]= (basePrice * qty) * tier4_discount;
                        }
                        else if (qty > data.tier5_range_start){
                            simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected]= (basePrice * qty) * tier5_discount;
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log('Something went wrong');
                        }

                    }
                    $j('.details'+vendor+ ' .priceBlock').append('<span>'+simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected]+'</span>');
                }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: That would mean that you aren't actually passing an array.

Comment: Maybe you should show us how you're casting the array into the function, as the function does'nt really matter ?

Comment: A collection does not have a length so perhaps your IDs is an object like {something:5}

Comment: there's likely some other function call to `updatePrices` which doesn't pass an `Array` like you're expecting - your problem's elsewhere ...

Comment: Okay guy's I put where the function is called above. See edit! Before I call the function IDs is logging as "5,3"

Comment: Can you show us `vendorInfo`?

Comment: @CaitlinHavener that's how arrays normally print: as a comma separated list of values.

Comment: you're passing it to venderInfo but showing updatePrices. please show the full path.

Comment: Okay, edited again. Second block of code is vendorInfo

Comment: Do you have a global variable called IDs? Since you are passing it in your callback function, IDs may be referring to the variable named `IDs` in a different context.

Comment: I do not have any global variables.

Comment: Inspecting the update button element it is weird : <a class="updatePriceButton" 5,4")"="" onclick="updatePrices(" href="#">
      Update
    </a>

Comment: See my response below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in this line:

```
$j('#qtyUpdateBox').append('<a href="#" class="updatePriceButton"     
 onclick="updatePrices('+IDs+')">Update</a>')
```

This casts `IDs` to a string for usage in that attribute.  (For an example, try `console.log("anteater " + IDs);`). You should probably setup an onclick listener programmatically.

```
$("#newElement").click(function() {
  updatePrices(IDs);
});
```

Comment: sorry, but this is not how it works. If do something like `var c = "text" + IDs` doesn't overwrite `IDs`.

Comment: Really that was the issue? Now I'm confused. Can someone please explain?

Comment: She's calling the function `updatePrices` there, so it absolutely passes in the string-casted IDs when the button is clicked, even if the variable IDs is never edited itself.  Keep in mind that `updatePrices` was the function she was having trouble with to begin with.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. I'm sorry...I obviously didn't put enough thought in my comment.